# How to set application_name for postgres connections in Elixir

Tags: elixir, ecto

The code below in config.exs will set the application_name in postgresql to "myapp".  How can I use the Elixir node name instead?  (using Kernel.node here causes an argument error)

```
config :db, DB.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  database: "ahv2",
  username: "troy",
  password: "pass",
  hostname: "localhost",
  parameters: [
    {:application_name, "myapp"}
  ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `init/2` callback added to Ecto in v2.1.0. The following code should work (but I have not tested it). You need to add this it to your `Repo` module after `use Ecto.Repo, ...`

```
def init(_, config) do
  {:ok, put_in(config, [:parameters, :application_name], Node.self |> to_string)}
end
```

Comment: calling Node.self int the callback causes same error as using the config

Comment: `(ArgumentError) argument error :erlang.iolist_size`, my Elixir foo is getting better and I realized Node.self returns an atom.  I edited and accepted your answer

Comment: Ah yeah, nodes are represented as atoms in the Erlang VM. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 0):

Changing application_name type inside parameters from a tuple to list do the work and it works for me.

```
config :db, DB.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  database: "ahv2",
  username: "troy",
  password: "pass",
  hostname: "localhost",
  parameters: [
    application_name, "myapp"
  ]
```